# Renewal of Meta GraphAPI token for use w/ business discovery

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using the [Instagram Business discovery functionality](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery/) to retrieve Instagram posts of a handful of Instagram business accounts. I'm running into an issue related to the tokens I use to get this information.

Every 90 days, I have to go into the Meta api explorer to get a new access token, because the 'long lived' tokens are only valid for 90 days. Preferably, I'd automatically refresh these tokens to remove the need to get a fresh token every time, but I couldn't figure out how to do this. Is this possible, and if so, how?

I've tried using the https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=....&client_secret=....&fb_exchange_token=<old_token> endpoint to refresh the token, both before and after expiry. When getting a new token before expiry, the expiration doesn't change. After expiry, it isn't possible to create new tokens.